# Spring Social Configurer - Cannot set postFailureUrl

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

In my SecurityConfig.java I apply the SpringSocialConfigurer, however when setting the postFailureUrl, I get a exception. Why cannot this be set? How to I configure the handler if needed?

```
.and()
        .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer()
            .postLoginUrl("/search")
            .alwaysUsePostLoginUrl(true)
            .postFailureUrl("/signin?login_error=s")
            )
    ;
```

> can't set postFailureUrl on unknown failureHandler, type is org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFailureHandler

btw. I also have regular formlogin and its own failurehandler

```
.failureHandler(securityLoginFailureHandler())
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be a bug. 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SOCIAL-456

A workaround is to create your own SpringSecurityConfigurer class and changing

```
if (postFailureUrl != null) {
        //filter.setPostFailureUrl(postFailureUrl);
        filter.setDefaultFailureUrl(postFailureUrl);
}
```